# Why zero index when set_userdata in CI_Session object?

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

I'm trying to set a custom Userdata variable - actually, an array.

I have queried MYSQL UserTable based on form input, and returned
the record as a result_array.

```
$this->session->set_userdata( 'Login', $ResultofUserMatch );
```

The dump of the userdata session variable is as follows:

```
[userdata] => Array
    (
        [session_id] => fda0d4f9a5b90c813b0850fa6e651b20
        [ip_address] => aa.bb.cc.dd
        [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100
        [last_activity] => 1319892314
        [Login] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ID] => 802
                        [Care Center Name] => george
                        [w3user] => georgewnyc@mail.com
                        [w3pass] => george
                        [w3code] => none
                        [role] => admin
                    )

            )

    )
```

Note that the Login array is contained, but that the data is at INDEX 0 - 
so they're at Login[0][role].

Am I doing something wrong? How do I get the data to be 'up one level'?

Answer (score 1):

When you get your result set you should call `$query->row()` instead of `$query->result()` which will fetch the first row from the result set, `result()` returns an array of all results in the set.

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')->from('userTable')->get();
$ResultofUserMatch = ($query->num_rows() !== 0 ? $query->row() : false);

if($ResultofUserMatch)
    $this->session->set_userdata( 'Login', $ResultofUserMatch );
```